# SmallRye Mutiny and Context Propagation

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

The (somewhat) new reactive API to Quarkus is awesome, but it introduces some complexity when writing code (much like in async code in JavaScript in my opinion).
How is it integrating with metrics/tracing/jwt APIs ? or anything that is passed by thread context?

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration is managed for you. Tracing and JWT are handle using context propagation. Metrics works flawlessly. Please report an issue if you see limitations or bugs.